# "Breathing" leds using FastLED and Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino, fastled

Uploading this to my Nano connected to a WS2812 led strip just freezes the current display and does not start the sequence. I can upload other Examples to the circuit and they work fine. Still new to FastLED and Arduino. The problem appeared when I added the for loop.

```
int breath;
void loop() { 
  // Fade in, Green, ~ 4 seconds
  leds[0] = CRGB::Green;
  for (int breath = 0; breath >= 255; breath++ ) {
    FastLED.setBrightness(breath);
    FastLED.show();
    delay(15);
    
  }
// Fade out, Aqua, ~8 seconds
  leds[0] = CRGB::Aqua;
  for (int breath = 255;breath <= 0; breath = breath-1 ) {
    FastLED.setBrightness(breath);
    FastLED.show();
   delay(31);
    
  }
}
```

Comment: You should set the color of the other leds, too.

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be related to this line

```
for (int breath = 255;breath <= 0; breath = breath-1 ) {
```

You're starting at 255, your test `breath<=0` will never be true so the for loop immediately kicks out. Switch from < to > and this might do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I made the following changes:

fade in should be <=255.

Since you're starting at 0 it will run until it reaches 255.

fade out should be >=0.

Since you're starting at 255 it will run until it reaches 0.